# How to seal the hole for a spigot through a stone wall

Tags: plumbing, stone

I have a faulty spigot, which goes from the basement of the house, between two joists, to the outside.  The outside is a stone wall which is about six inches thick.

There is already a hole through the stone wall, going into the basement.  I will easily be able to replace this spigot, but I don't know how to seal up the hole.

Do I need to have a sleeve around the new spigot piping?  I don't think there is a sleeve now, but I want to do this the right way according to code.  If I put a sleeve in, how do I seal it so that rain doesn't get into the house through this area?

I tried to Google this problem, but there doesn't seem to be much info on how to seal a pipe that goes through a stone wall.

Comment: There's not usually code for something like this. You can really use anything that's appropriate--pipe insulation putty, caulk, etc.

Comment: @isherwood Do you recommend Locktite PL concrete sealant?

Comment: If the spigot is itself firmly mounted (and doesn't rely on the pipe for mechanical stability), I'd use expanding foam.

Comment: Foam isn't water-resistant. I don't like using it for exterior exposure. Mark, read the label, bud. I've been off the scene for a few years and don't have a product catalog in my head.

Comment: @isherwood - [this manufacturer](http://greatstuff.dow.com/product/gaps-and-cracks.htm) says it is water resistant. I wouldn't expect it to last for decades and probably would eventually become waterlogged after prolonged continuous exposure. But unless the OP is filling a hole as wide as it is long, and assuming the exposed end is only ever splashed, I don't see it failing any time soon.

Comment: I would use silicone caulking from a tube. You could pump it into the hole and around the piping. It is water proof,  will last for years, and will give the piping support.

Comment: I fill brickwork and stone with mortar on the outside pressing it into the hole also provides some strength and if the hole is large enough set anchors so the twisting force on the faucet is not transfered to the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Fill any large gaps with sanded grout in the face of the stone, let that dry, then seal the outside of the pipe to the grout after it dries with Vulkem caulking.

From the inside of the house, seal the backside of the grout with expanding foam just enough to stop any air (1-2 inches deep). After that cures, fill the rest of the 3-4 inch cavity with fiberglass insulation. Most people would just fill the entire hole with expanding foam, but that makes it extremely difficult to work on it again in the future. It's a similar technique to installing new windows, first caulk, then air seal with expanding foam, then stuff the rest of the cavity with fiberglass insulation. Try not to over stuff the hole with the fiberglass, it's the best to keep it about the same density as it wants to be naturally out of the bag.

Instead of soldering the spigot directly to the pipe, I think you should solder a 3/4" MNPT fitting directly to the pipe, and then screw the new spigot onto those threads using teflon tape or thread sealant. This makes it easier to replace the spigot next time it fails. All you have to do is unscrew it, and screw in the replacement. It also makes it so you won't need to destroy your grout/vulkem/foam/insulation job down the road.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is call a plumber and ask or hire.  I had the same thing in my house and was told to mix ready mix cement then patch around the hole.  I used my hand to make it look like grout in the joints pressing the cement into the cavity.  Hope this helps...PC